# trying to import hyperv not working

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I'm writing a powershell script that will start/stop hyper-v VM's but it gave this message:

> The term 'Get-VM' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program

I found this helpful link:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/07decd82-270e-4dd0-b8e8-789d693099dd/powershell-getvm-error?forum=winserverpowershell [enter link description here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/07decd82-270e-4dd0-b8e8-789d693099dd/powershell-getvm-error?forum=winserverpowershell)

Then I added import-module HyperV but get this message:

> Import-Module: The specified module 'HyperV' was not loaded because no
>   valid module file was found in any module directory at
>   c:\scripts\startStopVMShell.ps1

I found a link that was helpful here: [Power shell: Import-Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622746/power-shell-import-module) [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622746/power-shell-import-module)

I tried this at the powershell cmd line:

Get-Module -listavailable

But it's not listing HyperV with any spelling.

I'm using Server 2008 R2.  How do I get the HyperV module on my server?  Or maybe I have it on my server but powershell is looking in the current directory instead of where the module is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hyper-V Module for Windows PowerShell was introduced as part of the Windows Server 2012 OS.  There is a CodePlex project under the "same" name that you might be able to port to 2008 R2.

[PowerShell Management Library for Hyper-V](https://pshyperv.codeplex.com/)

Let me know how that goes for you.
[Related blog post](http://trycatch.be/blogs/roggenk/archive/2010/02/08/powershell-management-library-for-hyper-v-r2.aspx).

Comment: Did you ever download from there?  When I go to the Gold download it lists PSHyperv-R2 under recommended download and when I select it, it's downloading a pdf file but I don't think it's downloading anything else, like the hyper-v module.

Comment: Like when I ran it on my pc, and then in powershell used <Get-Module -listavailable> it didn't list hyperv.

Comment: I did not install it Michele, so I am sorry that I cannot assist more on that front as I have no Hyper-V VMs running on 2008 R2.

Comment: I downloaded it.  Thanks a lot!  There was one download for the pdf file and one download for the zip file.